# How to upload image into parse server using back4app sdk in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, parse-platform, parse-server, back4app

I have to  upload image as a file into parse server using back4app sdk by using kotlin android.But file uploaded successfully at server but not in valid format. Question mark came at link.
Check from this image url link:-
https://parsefiles.back4app.com/0WEgKUxRM8YfbOL8wB3wK2BhspJ4I21JqoXyUWSB/382f3a5ce5fba12a55c49b87bc02b4fe_img.jpg

```
    val byte=“base64string…..”
    val myPhoto= ParseFile("myfile.png", byte.toByteArray())
    val jobApplication = ParseObject("Media")
    jobApplication.put("photo", myPhoto)
    jobApplication.put("name", "MA")
```

Comment: What do you by not in valid format?

Comment: When download the image from browser small question mark came

Comment: I just clicked on your download link, a white square image appeared. But I did not see any question marks.

Comment: What i was uploaded is not this image.I had uploaded the proper image.

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded the image of the link with the code above? The link contains a .jpg file while your code uploads a .png file.